# Calling different variable for output in struct

Tags: c, struct, output

I am currently working on a computer science project and have all but completed it, but am stuck on the last part. I have been provided with a large struct with which I am meant to create two additional classes to change its output.

As they are read from the file, students are inserted into the list in alphabetical order, rather than at the end or the beggining. If two or more students have the same name, they must be inserted in increasing order of age. It is guaranteed that in the test data no two students have the same name and the same age.

These two classes are comesBefore and insert, which are used to define whether a student should alphabetically precede another, and if so insert them into a list in the correct order. I have already created these functions in the provided code.

What I am unsure about now is how to actually call these functions into use, so that the output is actually alphabetised in the prescribed way.

For reference, Inputs should be put in the following way with an EOF termination:

```
Jenny Craig,47
Billy Bob,33
Jenny Craig,29
Simon Says,234
```

and the desired output for this would be:

```
Billy Bob (33)
Jenny Craig (29)
Jenny Craig (47)
Simon Says (234)
```

And my code is (quite large):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 80      // The longest line this program will accept
#define MAX_NUM_STUDENTS 500    // The maximum number of students this program can handle
#define MAX_NAME_SIZE 50        // The maximum allowable name length

// The declaration of the student record (or struct). Note that
// the struct contains the name as an array of characters, rather than
// containing just a pointer to the name as before.

typedef struct student_s Student;

struct student_s {
    char name[MAX_NAME_SIZE];
    int age;
    Student* next;              // Pointer to next student in a list
};

bool comesBefore(const Student* student1, const Student* student2) {
    int name_compare = strcmp(student1->name, student2->name);

    if (name_compare < 0) {
        return true;
    }
    else if (name_compare == 0) {
        int age1 = student1->age;
        int age2 = student2->age;
        if (age1 < age2) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

Student* insert(Student* student, Student* list) {
    Student* curr = NULL;
    Student* prev = NULL;
    if (list == NULL)
        return student;

    if (comesBefore(student, list)) {
        student->next = list;
        return student;
    }

    for (curr = list, prev = NULL;
         curr != NULL && comesBefore(student, curr) != true;
         prev = curr, curr = curr->next);

    assert(prev != NULL);

    student->next = curr;
    prev->next = student;
    return list;
}


// Create a pool of student records to be allocated on demand

Student studentPool[MAX_NUM_STUDENTS];  // The student pool
int firstFree = 0;
// Return a pointer to a new student record from the pool, after
// filling in the provided name and age fields. Returns NULL if
// the student pool is exhausted.
Student* newStudent(const char* name, int age) {
    Student* student = NULL;
    if (firstFree < MAX_NUM_STUDENTS) {
        student = &studentPool[firstFree];
        firstFree += 1;
        strncpy(student->name, name, MAX_NAME_SIZE);
        student->name[MAX_NAME_SIZE - 1] = '\0';  // Make sure it's terminated
        student->age = age;
        student->next = NULL;
    }
    return student;
}

// Read a single student from a csv input file with student name in first column,
// and student age in second.
// Returns: A pointer to a Student record, or NULL if EOF or an invalid
// student record is read. Blank lines, or lines in which the name is
// longer than the provided name buffer, or there is no comma in the line
// are considered invalid.
Student* readOneStudent(FILE* file)
{
    char buffer[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];  // Buffer into which we read a line from stdin
    Student* student = NULL;       // Pointer to a student record from the pool

    // Read a line, extract name and age

    char* cp = fgets(buffer, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, file);
    if (cp != NULL) {           // Proceed only if we read something
        char* commaPos = strchr(buffer, ',');
        if (commaPos != NULL && commaPos > buffer) {
            int age = atoi(commaPos + 1);
            *commaPos = '\0';  // null-terminate the name
            student = newStudent(buffer, age);
        }
    }
    return student;
}

// Reads a list of students from a given file. Input stops when
// a blank line is read, or an EOF occurs, or an illegal input
// line is encountered.
// Returns a pointer to the first student in the list or NULL if no
// valid student records could be read.
Student* readStudents(FILE *file)
{
    Student* first = NULL;     // Pointer to the first student in the list
    Student* last = NULL;      // Pointer to the last student in the list
    Student* student = readOneStudent(file);
    while (student != NULL) {
        if (first == NULL) {
            first = last = student;   // Empty list case
        }
        else {
            last->next = student;
            last = student;
        }
        student= readOneStudent(file);
    }
    return first;
}


// printOneStudent: prints a single student, passed by value
void printOneStudent(Student student)
{
    printf("%s (%d)\n", student.name, student.age);
}


// printStudents: print all students in a list of students, passed
// by reference
void printStudents(const Student* student)
{
    while (student != NULL) {
        printOneStudent(*student);
        student = student->next;
    }
}

// Main program. Read a linked list of students from a csv file, then display
// the contents of that list.
int main(void)
{
    FILE* inputFile = stdin;
    if (inputFile == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "File not found\n");
    }
    else {
        Student* studentList = readStudents(inputFile);
        printStudents(studentList);

        // The program could now do various things that make use of
        // the linked list, like deleting students and adding new ones,
        // but the program is already quite long enough!
    }
}
```

Comment: I've noticed you've got a studentPool array, but you're not using it. I think that you might want to re-think readOneStudent(file) so that it returns a single Student, and readStudents(file) so that it will iteratively readOneStudent over the entire file and insert these (using that insert function) into studentPool.

Answer (score 2):

Your implementation of `readStudents` is directly building the list, so keeping the order from the file. If you want the read to change the order, `readStudents` must call `insertStudent`. If you want `readStudents` to keep the order from the file, then you'll need an extra sort function.